# javascript function on a window object, when invoked, replaces that window's contents? (sometimes??)

Tags: javascript, function, window, return-value

For reasons which shall not be enumerated here, I've found it potentially useful to attach functions to the window object. However, I've discovered rather weird behavior.

```
<html><head><script>
function sideEffect() { console.log("Side effect happened. Wewt."); }
window.foo = function() {
    sideEffect();
    return true;
}
window.bar = function() {
    sideEffect();
}
</script></head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:window.foo();">Replaces entire window with "true"</a>
<br />
<a href="javascript:window.bar();">Doesn't</a>
</body></html>
```

Why exactly does invoking a function with a return value decide to replace the window's contents? This happens in Firefox and Opera, but not in IE9, Chrome, or Safari (all tested on Win7).

So the question is this: Is there some sort of documentation that specifies this behavior?
Or is this a (known) bug in FF/Opera?

---

[edit] Interestingly (according to answers and comments thusfar) it appears that the abuse of the `window` object is a red herring here.

Comment: I wouldn't play with the `window` object like that in the first place.

Comment: I wouldn't call JavaScript functions that way. It makes a lot of sense though: The browser displays the result of accessing the URI. In case the function does not return anything, the browsers seem to decide to still display the current page.

Comment: @Blender @Felix well normally I wouldn't either, but I'd like know why this happens rather than chalking it up to voodoo-magic JavaScript: The Bad Parts.

Comment: It is the same as doing `<a href="javascript:true">whatever</a>`

Comment: @Felix Kling - but the behavior is not consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly--the browser is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.

JavaScript lines are valid in the URL bar of web browsers, and the browser will execute them immediately.  (Try it: write an alert box in the URL bar, hit enter, and see what happens.)  By writing your JavaScript into the `href` of your anchor tags, you are setting the location of the browser (in other words, the URL) to that line of JavaScript.  Because one of your functions returns a value, the document is over written by that value; this is normal browser behavior.

Comment: Now *that* makes sense. Funny how only some browsers do exactly what I tell them to do, though ;)

Comment: +1, a decent explanation of what's happening.  All one needs to do is make sure the result is `undefined` or `null` to prevent the navigation.

Comment: ... except that Chrome and Safari do not do this.

Comment: @Pointy: Chrome does it for me -- `javascript:"Hello"`.  Safari doesn't.

Comment: @Andy E my Chrome won't do it, neither when I type the "javascript:" url into the address box nor when I do it programmatically.

Comment: @Pointy I will admit that I have not verified this on *every* web browser and version...but I have never found one that didn't work this way when I did test it.  Which version of Chrome you are using?

Comment: +1 This is what I wanted to express in my comment but it seems I did not succeed ;)

Comment: I don't see how this is doing what you're telling the browser to do. First, the function that returns nothing should open an empty page if you were truly telling the browser to go to a new location. Second, how do window.foo and sideEffect exist if it's going to a new location considering they live within that original page? What determines what code gets brought over to this new "location"?

Comment: @Bob For your first point, see Andy E's comment above.  Any value of `null`, `false`, or `undefined` in the href of an anchor causes the navigation to be cancelled--so the method that does not return a value is, on accident, cancelling the navigation--thus no blank page. You actually could "fix" (note the ironic quotes) the original code by re-writing it like this: `href="javascript:window.foo(); return false;"`

Comment: @Bob For your second point, the function is being executed prior to the navigation event (even though the URL is changing to the function call itself), and the value of the function is what is being rendered on the page; thus, seeing "true" on the page is the result of the function call after the function has been invoked.  You can see this in action, too, if you change the `foo()` function to return a string value such as "Hello"...the new page will say "Hello" instead of "true".

Comment: @Ken Taylor I'm using Chrome 10 on Linux.  Chrome 10 on Windows, Safari 5 on Windows, and IE9 all completely ignore the return value from a "javascript:" URL.

Comment: @Pointy I just tried it on Chrome 11 (lazily downloaded the latest), and I see what you mean. It's not a total departure; JavaScript in the URL does work (for example, try `javascript: alert('hello');` or `javascript: document.write("hello");`, which does replace the contents of the browser window), but the syntax in the question above does *not* have the same effect, as you say. It doesn't appear that the JavaScript-in-the-address-bar that is the problem, but what Chrome does with the values. Very interesting...

Comment: Yes, it *runs* the code, but it does not pay attention to the return value.  Really, the whole thing is an antique hack from the "Wild West" days of Netscape.

Comment: @Pointy Looking into this a bit further, the difference seems to be that Chrome does not automatically write the return value of a function call to the document window like IE and some other browsers.  If you set up a test like `javascript: function test() { return true; }; test();` and run it in the URL bar, nothing happens; if, however, you tweak the same code and explicity write the value of the function to the URL bar like `javascript: function test() { return true; }; document.write(test());`, then the word `true` appears in the window.

Comment: @Pointy LOL... *absolutely* agree with you that it is a hack, and I would never recommend it on purpose!! This has been more of an interesting academic exercise than anything else. :-)

Answer (score 1):

just put `void(0);` after your calls:

```
<a href="javascript:window.foo();void(0);">
```

If it still does that (I don't think it will), add an `|| false':

```
<a href="javascript:window.foo()||0;void(0);">
```

And ignore the "don't do that" comments -- there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, but all the `window.`'s are pointless (everything is in `window` anyway)

Comment: That's not really true - there **is** something wrong with what that code does, and what it is is the abuse of the "href" attribute stemming from an old, old hack introduced way back in the '90s.  There's no reason for new code not to use a modern event binding mechanism.

Comment: As a side note to my answer on this question, the reason cwolves code here works is because it is forcing a void to be returned to the href--just like the function call that does not return a value.

Comment: whilst `void[0];` will work, there's a small misunderstanding here. `void 0` or `void(0)` are what would normally be used, but `void anything` will work.  `void[0]` will unnecessarily create an array with `0` at the first element index. `void window.foo();` would be the most appropriate.

Comment: @Pointy - It's not a hack, `javascript:` is a protocol just like `http:`, `ftp:`, etc...  Just because there are more common ways to call JS code doesn't mean there's anything wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: Of course it's a hack.  Why on earth would you *prefer* that to using a DOM 0 event attribute ("onclick")?

Comment: @Pointy - I'm not advocating the method, just saying there's technically nothing wrong with it even if there are more common/better ways.

Comment: @cwolves the thing that's wrong with it is that the behavior is not the same in all browsers.

Comment: @Pointy - what browser doesn't understand a `javascript:` URI?

Comment: @cwolves read the OP - Chrome, Safari, and IE9 **do not** act the same way as Firefox and older IE versions. They "understand" the URL, I guess, but they certainly do not follow the old behavior of acting on the return value from a "javascript:" URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really bad form to use "javascript:" URLs like that anyway.  Create an "onclick" attribute if you absolutely must bind event handlers that way, or (better) do it with unobtrusive code.

That behavior is pretty old; the browsers that do it have been behaving that way since ancient times.